# How to make shadow on border-bottom?

Tags: css

I need to apply the border shadow on border-bottom by CSS3. I just want to apply CSS3 shadow on bottom. Is this possible?

Comment: This is covered in depth here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460129/drop-shadow-only-bottom-css3

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try:

```css
div{
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px #de1dde;
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px #de1dde;
 box-shadow:0px 1px 1px #de1dde;
  }
```

```html
<div>wefwefwef</div>
```

It generally adds a 1px blurred shadow 1px from the bottom of the box

```
box-shadow: [horizontal offset] [vertical offset] [blur radius] [color];
```

Comment: It is good. But I have only bottom border and I want to shade it. When I use above code, left and right shadow are also appear.

Comment: all these asnwers are not relevant - because it always create other unwanted shadows :)

Comment: Can't you see that there is no bottom shadow? There are shadows everywhere around element except for top

Comment: Downvoted because it generates a shadow around the whole element. Consider the answer from [Bill Bruilding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971880/how-to-make-shadow-on-border-bottom/3971917#27806891).

Answer (score 81):

The issue is shadow coming out the side of the containing div. In order to avoid this, the blur value must equal the absolute value of the spread value.

```css
div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -6px #222;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -6px #222;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -6px #222;
}
```

```html
<div>wefwefwef</div>
```

covered in depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460129/drop-shadow-only-bottom-css3)

Answer (score 19):

I'm a little late on the party, but its actualy possible to emulate borders using a `box-shadow`

```css
.border {
  background-color: #ededed;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.border-top {
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 0 cornflowerblue;
}

.border-right {
  box-shadow: inset -3px 0 0 cornflowerblue;
}

.border-bottom {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 0 cornflowerblue;
}

.border-left {
  box-shadow: inset 3px 0 0 cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="border border-top">border-top</div>
<div class="border border-right">border-right</div>
<div class="border border-bottom">border-bottom</div>
<div class="border border-left">border-left</div>
```

EDIT: I understood this question wrong, but I will leave the answer as more people might misunderstand the question and came for the answer I supplied.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, so it's appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

use `box-shadow` with no horizontal offset.

http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

eg.

```css
div {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 5px #888888;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 5px #888888;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div>wefwefwef</div>
```

There will be a slight shadow on the sides with a large blur radius (5px in above example)

Answer (score 10):

**New method for an old question**

[image]

It seems like in the answers provided the issue was always how the box border would either be visible on the left and right of the object or you'd have to inset it so far that it didn't shadow the whole length of the container properly.

This example uses the `:after` pseudo element along with a linear gradient with transparency in order to put a drop shadow on a container that extends exactly to the sides of the element you wish to shadow.

**Worth noting** with this solution is that if you use padding on the element that you wish to drop shadow, it won't display correctly.  This is because the `after` pseudo element appends it's content directly after the elements inner content.  So if you have padding, the shadow will appear inside the box.  This can be overcome by eliminating padding on outer container (where the shadow applies) and using an inner container where you apply needed padding.

*Example with padding and background color on the shadowed div:*

[image]

If you want to change the depth of the shadow, simply increase the `height` style in the `after` pseudo element.  You can also obviously darken, lighten, or change colors in the linear gradient styles.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.bottom-shadow {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bottom-shadow:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  background: transparent;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(   startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.bottom-shadow div {
  padding: 18px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-shadow">
  <div>
    Shadows, FTW!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the css:

```
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
```

Answer (score 0):

funny, that in the most answer you create a box with the text (or object), instead of it create the text (or object) div and under that a box with 100% width (or at least what it should) and with height what equal with your "border" px... So, i think this is the most simple and perfect answer:

`<h3>Your Text</h3><div class="border-shadow"></div>`

and the css:

```
    .shadow {
        width:100%;
        height:1px; // = "border height (without the shadow)!"
        background:#000; // = "border color!"
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1); // rbg = "border shadow color!"
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1); // rbg = "border shadow color!"
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1); // rbg = "border shadow color!"
```

}

Here you can experiment with the radius, etc. easy: https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow