# How to create a drop shadow only on one side of an element?

Tags: css

Is there a way to drop the shadow only on the bottom?. I have a menu with 2 images next to each other. I don't want a right shadow because it overlaps the right image. I don't like to use images for this so is there a way to drop it only on the bottom like:

`box-shadow-bottom: 10px #FFF;` or similar?

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #000;
box-shadow-bottom: 5px #000;
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=180, Color='#000000')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=180, Color='#000000');
```

Comment: Your accepted answer references `box-shadow-bottom` which does not exist, and is not supported by anyone. See http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/ for legit box-shadow techniques.

Comment: @Paul... I had a typo, its fixed.

Comment: The comments in your CSS example are misleading — `filter` will work in IE8 and IE9 as well. No need for `-ms-filter` in this case.

Comment: You may adapt this realistic inset css shadow : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20596554/1491212

Answer (score 273, accepted):

### UPDATE 4

Same as update 3 but with modern css (=fewer rules) so that no special positioning on the pseudo element is required.

```css
#box {
    background-color: #3D6AA2;
    width: 160px;
    height: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(10% - 10px);
    left: calc(50% - 80px);
}

.box-shadow:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:1px;
    z-index:-1;
    transform:scale(.9);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box-shadow"></div>
```

### UPDATE 3

All my previous answers have been using extra markup to get create this effect, which is not necessarily needed. I think this is a **much** cleaner solution... the only trick is playing around with the values to get the right positioning of the shadow as well as the right strength/opacity of the shadow. Here's a new fiddle, using [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-elements):

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/ARRRZ/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="box" class="box-shadow"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box {
    background-color: #3D6AA2;
    width: 160px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-top: -45px;
    margin-left: -80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.box-shadow:after {
    content: "";
    width: 150px;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 88px;
    margin-left: -75px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
}
```

### UPDATE 2

Apparently, you can do this with just an extra parameter to the box-shadow CSS as everyone else just pointed out. Here's the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/K88H9/821/

**CSS**

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #000000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #000000;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #000000;
```

This would be a better solution. The extra parameter that is added is described as:

> The fourth length is a spread
> distance. Positive values cause the
> shadow shape to expand in all
> directions by the specified radius.
> Negative values cause the shadow shape
> to contract.

### UPDATE

Check out the demo at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K88H9/4/

What I did was to create a "shadow element" that would hide behind the actual element that you would want to have a shadow. I made the width of the "shadow element" to be exactly less wide than the actual element by 2 times the shadow you specify; then I aligned it properly.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="element"></div>
    <div id="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 84px;
    position: relative;
}
#element {
    background-color: #3D668F;
    height: 54px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
#shadow {
    background-color: #3D668F;
    height: 8px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #000000;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #000000;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #000000;
}
```

### Original Answer

Yes, you can do this with the same syntax you have provided. The first value controls the horizontal positioning and the second value controls the vertical positioning. So just set the first value to `0px` and the second to whatever offset you'd like as follows:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px #000000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px #000000;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px #000000;
```

For more info on box shadows, check out these:

- http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/-moz-box-shadow#Browser_compatibility
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow

Comment: that does work, however the shadow doesn't look smooth. When I add the factor for smoothness box-shadow-bottom: 0px 5px #000000; it shows like this: http://i.imgur.com/CFYAc.png

Comment: You don't necessarily need to add an empty div to achieve a blurred shadow. That third value in the declaration: `box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #000000` is a blur value. See here [http://jsfiddle.net/K88H9/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/K88H9/7/). But you'll notice that there is a little bit of blur to the left and right of the element, where in Hristo's solution there is not.

Comment: There's no box-shadow-bottom property and this effect definitely does not need an extra element. Yuck.

Comment: `box-shadow-bottom`, while creative, doesn't actually exist.

Comment: chill guys... it was a friggin' typo

Comment: @Hristo a good idea for people not to get confused would be to edit your answer and to link to specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow

Comment: @gryzzly... I did edit my answer, I didn't see my typo until everyone pointed it out. Sorry about that.

Comment: How about another example with no extra markup but using `:after`

Comment: @JohnMagnolia... I updated my answer with a new solution using `:after`. Check it out! Let me know what you think :)

Comment: The solution with `:after` is acting weirdly. If i specify ANY z-index for the box, the "after" element displays on top of the box

Comment: @Hristo how can i increase the height of that shadow?

Comment: @MoathHowari... `box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #232323;` 2nd value controls height

Comment: @Hristo Please note that you could probably do away with the `-moz` and `-webkit` prefixes as they are used in almost non existent browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

Comment: these solutions aren't quite working as good as everyone thinks.  Your first update with the wrapper actually does the best job of hiding the shadow on the sides.  Make the boxes that you are shadowing WHITE to really see the shadows.  The pseudo-element solution in update 3 comes very close, pretty cool idea, but if the box is white, you will see the shadow comes up the sides a few pixels

Comment: @MilkyTech... good catch. the shadow coming up the sides is definitely annoying. any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Look at theengineear's answer: In most cases a far better (and a very clean) solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56654875/760777

Answer (score 82):

Just use the spread parameter to make the shadow smaller:

```css
.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px black;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -4px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">Some content</div>
```

Live demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/a8f8ba527f5cff607327

To not see any shadow on the sides, the (absolute value of the) spread radius (4th parameter) needs to be the same as the blur radius (3rd parameter).

Comment: this doesn't actually work.  at first glance it appears as if the shadow is only on the bottom but in fact it still spreads past the sides.  Everbody's examples are with a fairly dark blue box...make the box white and you will see all of the shadow.

Comment: @Chris M: just increment the spread parameter: try 4 example with `box-shadow:0 8px 4px -6px` and you'll see only the bottom shadow!

Comment: once again, **make the box WHITE** as in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/49xpU/1032/) and you will still see shadow all the way up the sides and also it now doesn't make it all the way across the bottom.  how far are you willing to go on the spread parameter to get rid of the sides?  Also, probably best for someone with 151 rep to not edit the answer of someone with 7k rep.  leave it in a comment.

Comment: @T30 Of course you can eventually get rid of the sides by reducing the spread parameter even further.  But now your shadow isn't anywhere close to the width of your box.  You have an 84px box with a 72px shadow.

Comment: Updated answer. But basically, short of reducing the spread radius and adjusting the Y offset, there’s not much one can do. Maybe use a gradient instead of a shadow?

Also, I don’t mind people editing my posts, but I do not appreciate people editing my posts to add sentences written in some Engrish-like language. I’m not a native English speaker either and I understand the challenges, but if I was editing someone else’s post, I’d feel enough responsibility to at least double-check that what I added sort of makes sense and the grammar isn’t embarrassingly wrong.

Comment: @T30 Your editing and your attitude here are not appropriate. If you wish to post a better answer, *post it yourself*; do not edit someone else's in this manner.

Comment: Look at theengineear's answer: In most cases a far better (and a very clean) solution, see stackoverflow.com/a/56654875/760777

Answer (score 33):

If you have a fixed color on the background, you can hide the side-shadow effect with two **masking shadows** having the same color of the background and blur = 0, example:

```
box-shadow: 
    -6px 0 white,         /*Left masking shadow*/
    6px 0 white,          /*Right masking shadow*/
    0 7px 4px -3px black; /*The real (slim) shadow*/
```

Note that the black shadow must be the last, and has a negative spread (-3px) in order to prevent it from extendig beyond the corners.

Here the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QbY3C/556/) (change the color of the masking shadows to see how it *really* works).

```css
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid pink;
    box-shadow: -6px 0 white, 6px 0 white, 0 7px 5px -2px black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Would be much better to use the `transparent` color for the masking shadows, no?

Comment: @T30 awesome, but note that with a transparent mask you shouldn't need a fixed color background ;)

Comment: I tested it better, and transparent shadow [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/ac6nLxuz/), so I rolled back the last edits

Comment: Look at theengineear's answer: In most cases a far better (and a very clean) solution, see stackoverflow.com/a/56654875/760777

Answer (score 33):

You could also use `clip-path` to clip (hide) all overflowing edges but the one you want to show:

```
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px black;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 200%, 0 200%);
}
```

See [clip-path (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path). The arguments to `polygon` are the *top-left* point, the *top-right* point, the *bottom-right* point, and the *bottom-left* point. By setting the bottom edge to `200%` (or whatever number bigger than `100%`) you constrain your overflow to only the bottom edge.

**Examples:**

[image: example of boxes with top right bottom and left box-shadow isolated with clip-path]

```css
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 5px rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.shadow-top {
  clip-path: polygon(0% -20%, 100% -20%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
.shadow-right {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 120% 0%, 120% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
.shadow-bottom {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 120%, 0% 120%);
}
.shadow-left {
  clip-path: polygon(-20% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, -20% 100%);
}

.shadow-bottom-right {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 120% 0%, 120% 120%, 0% 120%);
}

/* layout for example */
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #338484;
  color: #fff;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">none</div>
<div class="box shadow shadow-all">all</div>
<div class="box shadow shadow-top">top</div>
<div class="box shadow shadow-right">right</div>
<div class="box shadow shadow-bottom">bottom</div>
<div class="box shadow shadow-left">left</div>
<div class="box shadow shadow-bottom-right">bottom right</div>
```

Comment: So... in basic terms, clip-path is the overflow: hidden property on steroids. This is clean. ;)

Comment: an extension to this answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65807809/8620333

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you're after?

```css
.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px white, 0 6px 4px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px white, 0 6px 4px black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px white, 0 6px 4px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">wefwefwef</div>
```

Comment: Love it when people simply don't understand. Yes, he's messing with the spread of the first shadow (white) that will cover the margin of the real shadow (black). This is the only sane way to obtain a perfect unidirectional shadow. Specially useful when you need to have the same shadow on 2 parts of a menu.

Answer (score 5):

Another idea based on [the answer of @theengineear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56654875/8620333) where I will use `inset` instead of `polygon`. It's easier since it works the same way as margin or padding. I will also rely on CSS variable to easily define all the different cases.

```css
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 5px rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5);
  clip-path:inset(var(--t,0) var(--r,0) var(--b,0) var(--l,0))
}

.top { --t:-100%; }
.right { --r:-100%;}
.bottom { --b:-100%; }
.left { --l:-100%;}


/* layout for example */

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #338484;
  color: #fff;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">none</div>
<div class="box shadow top right left bottom">all</div>
<div class="box shadow top">top</div>
<div class="box shadow right">right</div>
<div class="box shadow bottom">bottom</div>
<div class="box shadow left">left</div>
<div class="box shadow bottom right">bottom right</div>
<div class="box shadow bottom top">top bottom</div>
<div class="box shadow left top right">top left right</div>
<div class="box shadow left right"> left right</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's always better to read [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow). There is no `box-shadow-bottom` property, and as Lea points out you should always place the un-prefixed property at the bottom, after the prefixed ones.

So it's:

```css
.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">Some content</div>
```

Comment: There's shadow from the sides

Answer (score 2):

How about just using a containing div which has overflow set to hidden and some padding at the bottom? This seems like much the simplest solution.

Sorry to say I didn't think of this myself but saw it [somewhere else](http://blog.w3conversions.com/2011/09/css3-spread-value-and-box-shadow-on-one-side-only#comment-3737).

> Using an element to wrap the element getting the box-shadow and a overflow: hidden on the wrapper you could make the extra box-shadow disappear and still have a usable border.
>   This also fixes the problem where the element is smaller as it seems, because of the spread.
>
> Like this:
>
> ```
> #wrapper { padding-bottom: 10px; overflow: hidden; }
> #elem { box-shadow: 0 0 10px black; }
> ```
>
> Content goes here
>
> Still a clever solution when it has to be done in pure CSS!

As said by [Jorgen Evens](http://blog.w3conversions.com/2011/09/css3-spread-value-and-box-shadow-on-one-side-only#comment-3737).

Comment: +1 for the solution. In addition to the `padding-bottom` (let's say 5px), you could also set a negative `margin-bottom` (of -5px) to compensate for the added space.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed a shadow but only under an image and set in slightly left and right. This worked for me:

```
.box-shadow {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 35px 30px -25px #888888;
      -moz-box-shadow: 5px 35px 30px -25px #888888;
           box-shadow: 5px 35px 30px -25px #888888;
}
```

The element this is applied to is a page-wide image (980px x 300px).

If it helps when fiddling with the settings, they run as follows:

horizontal shadow, vertical shadow, blur distance, spread (i.e. shadow size), and color.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to look up shadow:

```
.header{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -8px 73px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -8px 73px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 -8px 73px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

this code is currently using on stackoverflow web.

Answer (score 1):

You need fist to know each value is for what:

```css
/* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```

To apply a shadow effect only on one side of an element set the blur value to a **positive** number and set the spread value to the same size but with a **negative** sign. Depending on which side you want the shadow on, set the offset value as follows:

- Top shadow: `offset-x`: `0 and offset-y: -5px`
- Right shadow: `offset-x`: `5px and offset-y: 0`
- Bottom shadow: `offset-x`: `0 and offset-y: 5px`
- Left shadow: `offset-x`: `-5px and offset-y: 0`

```css
.box{
    margin: 2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.shadow-all{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.shadow-top {
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 3px -3px #00000030;
}
  
.shadow-right {
    box-shadow: 5px 0 3px -3px #00000030;
}
  
.shadow-bottom {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 3px -3px #00000030;
}
  
.shadow-left {
    box-shadow: -5px 0 3px -3px #00000030;
}
```

```html
        
    <div class="box shadow-all">
        Shadow All 
    </div>
    <div class ="box shadow-top">
        Shadow Top
    </div>
    <div class ="box shadow-right">
        Shadow Right
    </div>
    <div class ="box shadow-bottom">
        Shadow Bottom
    </div>
      
    <div class ="box shadow-left">
        Shadow left
    </div>
```

Read more [here](https://cssf1.com/snippet/add-a-box-shadow-to-only-one-side-of-an-element#:%7E:text=To%20apply%20a%20shadow%20effect%20only%20on%20one,follows%3A%20Top%20shadow%3A%20offset-x%3A%200%20and%20offset-y%3A%20-5px) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

If your background is solid (or you can reproduce it using CSS), you can use linear gradient that way:

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 5px, #fff 5px, #fff 100%)
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Foobar</p>
<p>test</p>
</div>
```

This will generate a 5px gradient at the bottom of the element, from black at 30% opacity to completely transparent. The rest of the element has white background. Of course, changing the last 2 color stops of the linear gradient, you could make the background completely transparent.

Answer (score 0):

This code pen (not by me) demonstrates a super simple way of doing this and the other sides by themselves quite nicely:

```
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #333;
```

https://codepen.io/zeckdude/pen/oxywmm

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do a gradient on the bottom - this was helpful for me because the shadow I wanted was on an element that was already semi-transparent, so I didn't have to worry about any clipping:

```
&:after {
      content:"";
      width:100%;
      height: 8px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -8px;
      left: 0;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    }
```

Just make the "bottom" and "height" properties match and set your rgba values to whatever you want them to be at the top / bottom of the shadow

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

General syntax:

```
selector {
   box-shadow: topBoxShadow, bottomBoxShadow, rightBoxShadow, leftBoxShadow
}
```

Example: we want to make only a bottom box shadow with red color,

so to do that we have to set all the sides options where we have to set the bottom box shadow options and set all the others as empty as follow:

```
.box {
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent ,0 0 10px red, 0 0 0 transparent, 0 0 0 transparent
     -o-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent ,0 0 10px red, 0 0 0 transparent, 0 0 0 transparent
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent ,0 0 10px red, 0 0 0 transparent, 0 0 0 transparent
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent ,0 0 10px red, 0 0 0 transparent, 0 0 0 transparent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inset top and bottom box-shadow

```css
   
 .cont{
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .shadow {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
            height:100%;
        box-shadow: inset gray 0px 50px 15px 0px,inset gray 0px -50px 15px 0px;
        padding-right: 30px;
        margin-left: -15px;
    }
```

```html
<div class=cont>
    <div class=shadow></div>
        
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

update on someone else his answer transparant sides instead of white so it works on other color backgrounds too.

```css
body {
  background: url(http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2016/03/29/beautiful-nature-backgrounds_042320876_304.jpg)
}

div {
  background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png) center center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 7px 7px -5px black;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

inner shadow

```css
 .shadow {
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 9px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 9px #000;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 9px #000;
 }
```

```html
<div class="shadow">wefwefwef</div>
```