# Drop shadow only on one edge

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [drop shadow only bottom css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460129/drop-shadow-only-bottom-css3)

With CSS3, how would one make a drop shadow only appear on the bottom edge of a DIV? I would like it to work in FF4, IE9, C10.

[image: drop shadow]

Setting a positive Y-offset doesn't quite look right - I can still see faint remnants of the shadow the other edges and the shadow on the bottom edge is too stiff.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460129/drop-shadow-only-bottom-css3

Comment: @thirtydot: Wow, this question has been asked to death. This year alone I've seen at least 6 such questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference the link @thirtydot posted. I would use two div. This would make it exactly like your posted image.

```
#container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 210px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#element{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:aqua;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #888;
    float: left;
}
<div id="container">
<div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. It can also gracefully degrade on IE. The second div can just be a transparent hard-edged rectangle for a minimalistic style of drop shadow.