# box-shadow only on one side of an element?

Tags: css, stylesheet, styling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [drop shadow only bottom css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460129/drop-shadow-only-bottom-css3)

I've been struggling with this for a while and wondered if there is a way to create a `box-shadow` that has a blur but only appears on one side of an element.

I have setup a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhKJF/), You can see that the blur still shows on the top and bottom of the element? Any ideas?

Comment: I've taken a look at this link WTP, but it doesn't perform as well as I need it to on bigger shadows.

Answer (score 0):

me again.

I have figured this out. I use the `:before` CSS selector like so

```
.element:before
{
content:'';
position:absolute;
left:-5px;
right:100%;
top:0;
bottom:0;
box-shadow: -10px 0 20px #aaa;
}
```

I have edited my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhKJF/1/) if anyone needs to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a perfect solution but you can create a container for your div and hide 3 side by reducing the width of the inner div and playing with the float left or right depending on wich side you want the shaddow. I guest with fixed witdh it will be easier to manage.

Take a look at the example : http://jsfiddle.net/etienne_carre/rhKJF/4/