# How do I ONLY add a box-shadow to the bottom with the following css?

Tags: css

I have the following css code:

```
     box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888;
```

How do I make it so that only the bottom border shows.  I have a blur radius so not sure what to change or add to the above snippet.

Comment: What is the HTML used for the element, does it sit 100% width in a container? you could use `overflow:hidden` on the container if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decrease the spread distance based on the blur radius (i.e. spread distance needs to compensate for addition of blur).  Don't forget to adjust offset as well to compensate for reduction in spread.

```
box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px -3px #888;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p469p/

You also only need `box-shadow`.  Mozilla and Webkit have supported it [for a long time](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow).

And for more informations see [drop shadow only bottom css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460129/drop-shadow-only-bottom-css3)

Comment: Remember that your 'shadowed' element might need a bottom-margin if it is to be over another element witch has overflow:hidden. The shadow is 'outside' the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <style> 
            div {
            box-shadow: 0px 2px #888;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.
    </div>
</body>
```

Thats the only way

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the solutions posted in this StackOverflow:

[drop shadow only bottom css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460129/drop-shadow-only-bottom-css3)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a linear gradient on the background:

```
background:linear-gradient(transparent 0%, transparent 90%,rgba(0,0,0,.7) 90%,transparent 100%);
```