# Increase height of bottom shadow

Tags: html, css

I have div which has a shadow on bottom as [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460129/drop-shadow-only-bottom-css3)
what i need is the same answer but i want to increase the height of the shadow,
code :

```
.box-shadow:after {

    content: "";
    margin-top:1px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p8g77/1/)
,all what i need is to increase the height of the shadow ,please JSfiddle answer 
i want if possible the shadow looks like this image with full screen widh:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29BfJ.png)

**UPDATED**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't increase the size of the blur radius on only one direction (X or Y).  I made the X offset `50px`, and the blur radius `10px`.

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 50px 10px 4px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 50px 10px 4px #000;
        box-shadow: 0px 50px 10px 4px #000;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p8g77/2/

Answer (score 1):

The shadow is always in proportion with the div itself, however if you look at the syntax of `box-shadow` you will see there are several options:

> Formal syntax:
>
> `[inset? && [ <offset-x> <offset-y> <blur-radius>? <spread-radius>? <color>? ]]`

In other words, you can change the offset, or make it bigger in every direction, but you can't change **only** the height unless you change the height of the `div` it's applied to.

Changing to

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 10px #000000;
```

Would make the shadow 8 pixels bigger in all directions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the format of box-shadow:`box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;`
So it will look something like this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 8px 2px #000000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 8px 2px #000000;
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 8px 2px #000000;
```

Here's more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try stacking shadows:

```
box-shadow: 0 0  8px 2px #000000,
            0 0 25px 2px #000000,
            0 0 40px 2px #000000,
            0 0 50px 2px #000000;
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p8g77/3/)**