# Having trouble replicating SVG using pure CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to replicate an SVG with pure CSS and I'm having a little bit of trouble. I've found that `radial-gradient` is the best approach for this.

Here's what I have:

```css
.css {
    width: 1155px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    color: #000000;
}

.css::before {
                background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 10%, transparent, transparent);
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 0.6rem;
        min-width: 1250px;
        position: absolute;
                left: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='1150' height='26' fill='none'>
  <g clip-path='url(#clip0)'>
    <path fill='url(#paint0_radial)' d='M0 13h1155v26H0z' />
  </g>
  <defs>
    <radialGradient
      id='paint0_radial'
      cx='0'
      cy='0'
      r='1'
      gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
      gradientTransform='matrix(0 13 -577.5 0 577.5 26)'
    >
      <stop stop-color='#D8D8D8' />
      <stop offset='1' stop-color='#D8D8D8' stop-opacity='0' />
    </radialGradient>
    <clipPath id='clip0'>
      <path fill='#fff' d='M0 0h1155v26H0z' />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
    
<div class="css"></div>
```

The shadow effect is not quite the same. I've also tried using `box-shadow`, something like,

```
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    min-width: 1250px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -40px 20px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

But `radial-gradient` looks more natural. How can I tune this a little more to look like the svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decrease the opacity of the gradient.
try this:

```css
.css {
                background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 10%, transparent,       transparent);
        margin-top:70px;
        display: block;
        height: 30px; /* height */
        min-width: 1250px;
        position: absolute;
                left: 0;
}
.css::after{
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 15px;  /* height/2 */
        background:white;
        margin-top:15px;  /* height/2 */
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='1150' height='26' fill='none'>
  <g clip-path='url(#clip0)'>
    <path fill='url(#paint0_radial)' d='M0 13h1155v26H0z' />
  </g>
  <defs>
    <radialGradient
      id='paint0_radial'
      cx='0'
      cy='0'
      r='1'
      gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'
      gradientTransform='matrix(0 13 -577.5 0 577.5 26)'
    >
      <stop stop-color='#D8D8D8' />
      <stop offset='1' stop-color='#D8D8D8' stop-opacity='0' />
    </radialGradient>
    <clipPath id='clip0'>
      <path fill='#fff' d='M0 0h1155v26H0z' />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
    
<div class="css"></div>
```

[shadow box solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56654875)