# Directional Shadows in QML

Tags: qt, qml, shadow

Is it possible to define a directional shadow on a QML element, so that the shadow will only be thrown on one side of the object?

I could only find the `DropShadow` element. But that generates a shadow on all sides, which can be moved around using offsets. But the shadow will always be bigger than the original object.

I want something very much like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56654875/3686675) to a question on shadows in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your link that [attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460129/how-to-create-a-drop-shadow-only-on-one-side-of-an-element/56654875#56654875)

**This use color Gradient** , Not confuse with shadow .

```
  Rectangle
{
    x: 150
    y: 111
    width: 152
    height: 112
    color: "#1e8784"

    Rectangle
    {
        x: 0
        y: 97
        width: 152
        height: 15
        color: "#f159bf"

        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
                position: 0.00;
                color: "#ff20a2";
            }
            GradientStop {
                position: 0.42;
                color: "#f583cf";
            }
            GradientStop {
                position: 1.00;
                color: "#ffffff";
            }
        }

    }


}
```

[image: out put]

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for! Going from a color to transparency in the gradient emulates "shadow" behaviour.