# How create white shadow in border box, in h2

Tags: html, css

How can I add a box-shadow in the bottom of my border, in the bottom of my H2??

HTML:

```
<h2> Hi </h2>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
   border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/auszoy6g/)

Comment: This question could be a duplicate of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3971880/541591

Answer (score 0, accepted):

key is playing with the negative value on the spread value, so something like:

```
h2 {
   border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
   box-shadow: 0 3px 8px -5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use:

```
div h2 {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px grey;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_shadows.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    position: relative;
}

h2:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px red;
}
```

```html
<h2> Hi </h2>
```

I think you need box-shadow :)